# kaldi python2 binary issue

Tags: python-2.7, binary, symlink, kaldi

I am installing kaldi in ubuntu 18.04. python2.7 is one of the dependencies to install kaldi. I have installed python2.7 by sudo apt-get install pytho2.7. Then to check the prerequisites run
extras/check_dependencies.sh. The result showing - "python2.7 is installed, but the python2 binary does not exit. Creating a symlink and adding this to tools/env.sh"
What is the next step to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should add symlink to python2.7 binary:

```
ln -fs /usr/bin/python2.7 $(KALDI_ROOT)/tools/python/python2
```

Where $(KALDI_ROOT) is a root directory of Kaldi source code

Answer (score 1):

i just input 'ln -fs /usr/bin/python2.7'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).